# Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I tried to use `getGEO` from `GEOquery` package to upload a data from ncbi site.
Here is my code:

```
gset <- GEOquery::getGEO("GSE90964", GSEMatrix =TRUE, getGPL=FALSE)
```

I got this error:

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open the connection

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your code works fine on my side.

Comment: I can't see a `GEOquery` package on CRAN so where did you get it from and what version is it?

Comment: Hello i want to analysis micro array Data( GSE90964 ) With R , so i copy R script in my Rstudio, when I write this code gset <- getGEO("GSE90964", GSEMatrix =TRUE, getGPL=FALSE). this error was appeared (Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : cannot open the connection) .